# Using a parameter in Kendo ui template of checkboxes in TreeViewOptions

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-template

I am trying to create a class that create a generic kendo TreeView that the tree can have items with checkbox and items without checkbox. 
So, I created a class with the flowing c'tor:

```
    constructor(checkable: boolean = false) {

    // Create the treeview options
    const treeViewOptions: kendo.ui.TreeViewOptions = {
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true,
            template: "# if (item.level() > 0) { #" +
                "<input type='checkbox' #= item.checked ? 'checked' : '' #>" +
                "# } #" 

            }, 
    // ... The rest of the treeViewOptions ...

    }
```

Now, all items that their item.level==0 are without checkbox. 
I want that if the parameter "checkable" of the c'tor is false, than all the items in the tree will not have checkboxes. I didn't know how to pass the "checkable" parameter into the template. I wanted something like this:

```
        checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: true,
        template: "# if (checkable && item.level() > 0) { #" +
            "<input type='checkbox' #= item.checked ? 'checked' : '' #>" +
            "# } #" 

        },
```

Please help me with that and if you think that there is more elegant way to do that I will be happy to hear. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the template be an anonymous function and have it emit different template strings depending on constructor argument.

```
template: function () {
  if (checkable) {
    return ... template string that allows checkboxes at item level > 0 ...
  } else {
    return ... simpler template string that has no checkboxes anywhere ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I wrote and it worked `template: (function () {
                    if (checkableChildren) {
                        return ' # if (item.level() > 0) { #' +
                            "<input type='checkbox' #= item.checked ? 'checked' : '' #>" +
                            '# } #';
                    }
                    return "";
                })()`